# $M_x$ maximal ideal in $C(X)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, ideals, c-star-algebras

let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space.consider commutative Banach algebra $C(X)$.

let for $x\in X$ is fixed. define$$M_x=\{f:f\in C(X)\  \text{and}\  f(x)=0\}$$.

then $M_x$ is proper two sided ideal. but is $M_x$  maximal ideal in $C(X)$

any hint

Comment: next exercise: all maximal ideals of $C(X)$ are of this form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is an ideal and $M_x\varsubsetneq M$, then there's a $f\in M$ such that $f(0)\neq0$. Now, note that$$1=\frac{f(0)}{f(0)}=\frac f{f(0)}-\frac{f-f(0)}{f(0)}\in M.$$

Comment: why does $\frac{f-f(0)}{f(0)} \in M$ ??

Comment: ok. i got it . it belong to kernal.thanks

Comment: @paarth It has value $0$ at $0$ so is in $M_x$ hence in $M$.

Answer (score 2):

$e_x: C(X)  \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $e_x(f) =f(x)$. Then $e_x$ is a epimorphism of unitary rings. $M_x = \ker(e_x)$ and so $C(X) / M_x \simeq \mathbb{R}$ which is a field. So $M_x$ is maximal (modding out gives a field).